# How to conditionally parse expressions with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat, which shows conditional sections of markup. However all the expression in the markup are still being parsed and therefore throwing exceptions when they are undefined.

E.G: **if item.discriminator is VoteOnNodeRcNotification, the other ng-show will still parse**, and for example `{{ item.nodeCommentText }}` won't exist

i.e: (inside the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-show="item.discriminator == 'VoteOnNodeRcNotification'" class="type-specific">
                <a class="outer-link self-clear" ng-href="{{ nodeLink(item.nodeId, item.nodeText) }}">
                    <small class="rep-change-mag" ng-class="getAdjustedCss(item.amountAdjusted)">
                        {{ friendlyAmountAdjusted(item, item.amountAdjusted) }}
                    </small>
                    <p class="rep-change-assoc">
                        Edit accepted: {{ item.nodeText }}
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="item.discriminator == 'VoteOnNodeCommentRcNotification'" class="type-specific">
                <a class="outer-link self-clear" ng-href="{{ nodeLink(item.nodeCommentId, item.nodeCommentText) }}">
                    <small class="rep-change-mag" ng-class="getAdjustedCss(item.amountAdjusted)">
                        {{ friendlyAmountAdjusted(item, item.amountAdjusted) }}
                    </small>
                    <p class="rep-change-assoc">
                        Vote up: {{ item.nodeCommentText }}
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ''ng-if'' for that. Just like ng-show, but the content is not generated when the condition is falsy.

Comment: Thank you! Haha that's why I love stack :-)

Answer (score 1):

ng-show just shows/hides the element, so it still exists in the DOM and therefore will always be evaluated. You can either set a default value for item.discriminator in your controller. For example..

```
$scope.item = {};
$scope.item.discriminator = null;
```

null is still falsy and therefore will be hidden by ng-show, but won't throw an error because it is actually defined. Another options is to use ng-if instead of ng-show, which actually removes the element from the DOM when the expression is falsy